# How can I rename a Shadow Property in Entity Framework Core without explicitly adding a foreign key?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I tried to establish **One-To-Many** relation using [**Shadow foreign key**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many#required-one-to-many-with-shadow-foreign-key). But it created a column in database with a different naming convention.

It created it as:

```
AuthorId
```

What I want:

```
author_id
```

The **Book** model with *shadow foreign key*:

```
    [Table("books")]
    public class Book
    {
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }
```

The **Author** model:

```
    [Table("authors")]
    public class Author
    {
        public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't want to add **ForeignKey** explicitly. Is there a way to give a name to the shadow property? And then migrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the shadow property explicitly using `.Property<int>("AuthorId")`. Then use `.HasColumnName("author_id")` to specify the desired column name in the database

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .Property<int>("AuthorId") // Shadow property
    .HasColumnName("author_id") // DB Column
    .IsRequired();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this using **FluentAPI**:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
        .HasOne(b => b.Author)
        .WithMany(a => a.Books)
        .HasForeignKey("author_id")
        .HasConstraintName("FK_books_authors_author_id")
        .IsRequired();
}
```

Then I just proceeded to migrate, and it changed the database.